# Issue with rand range value in Pygame class code, raise value error

Tags: python, function, pygame

My code keeps coming up with the following error whenever I run it:
*raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)*

I tried changing the values but nothing seems to be working i was wondering what the issue may be? the section of code is displayed bellow:

```py
import pygame
vec=pygame.math.Vector2
from os import path
import sys
import random 
from random import choice, randrange, uniform 

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self._layer = mob_layer
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.mobs
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image_up = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(566, 510, 122, 139)
        self.image_up.set_colorkey(black)
        self.image_down = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(568, 1534, 122, 135)
        self.image_down.set_colorkey(black)
        self.image = self.image_up
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = choice([-100, width + 100])
        self.vx = randrange(1, 4)
        if self.rect.centerx > width:
            self.vx *= -1
        self.rect.y = randrange(height / 2)
        self.vy = 0
        self.dy = 0.5
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Where `height` come from in `self.rect.y = randrange(height / 2)`? Also does this you whole code that raises the problem? If not please paste the entire code

Comment: `randrange(height / 2)` -> `randrange(height // 2)`

Comment: @DavidS Avoid asking OP for their entire code. OP should never include all their code, but rather a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `randrange` needs to be integral values. Use the `//` (floor division) operator rather than the `/` (division) operator:

<s>`self.rect.y = randrange(height / 2)`</s>

```py
self.rect.y = randrange(height // 2)
```